# How do I open .gif file using tkinter without getting error "Too early to create image"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I cannot start my Python program. I've a problem that I cannot open a .gif file, and I cannot figure out how!

I keep getting a long error message:

> `"RuntimeError: Too early to create image"`

I have moved the gif files into the same project file as the code, and I tried looking online, but everyone uses different packages, and I just cannot find a way around it. I also have the gifs open on pycharm.

**Here is my code:**

```
import random
from tkinter import *


sign = random.randint(0, 1)

if (sign == 1):
   photo = PhotoImage(file="X.gif")
else:
    photo = PhotoImage(file="O.gif")
```

My overall goal is to show an image like a finished tic tac toe game, with randomly placed X's and O's, and there does not have to be any specific order like 3 in a row.  Here is the homework problem:

> Display a frame that contains nine labels. A label may display an image icon for X or an image icon for O, as shown in Figure 12.27c. What to display is randomly decided.
>
> Use the `Math.random()` method to generate an integer 0 or 1, which corresponds to displaying an X or O image icon. These images are in the files x.gif and o.gif.

Comment: you mentioned two different erorr messages. Which one is your problem ?

Comment: To use `PhotoImage` you may have to create main window `Tk()` first. And `Too early to create image` can means you use `PhotoImage` before you created `Tk()`

Comment: If you have error `“no such file or directory”` then try `"/full/path/to/image/X.gif"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see from the code that you're using `PhotoImage` before creating a main window gives you an `Runtime error` and it is clearly said in the error that *"Too early to create image"* means the image cannot be create if there is no active `Tk` window.

The reason why some people prefer the use other module because it give you more flexibility to resize, reshape, invert and more. ( By the way it could **Pillow** module `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` [How to use PIL in Tkinter](https://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm) ).

### **Now back to your code.**

1. You can randomise "O" and "X" images without even use of `if-else`.
2. I created main window before creating the Image.
3. Make sure the images you using are in the same directory.

---

```
import random
from tkinter import *

sign = random.choice( ["X.gif", "O.gif"] )

print(sign,"photo has been selected")

root = Tk()

Photo = PhotoImage(file=sign)

display_photo = Label(root, image=Photo)
display_photo.pack()

mainloop()
```